# Javascript: form validation with a∨(b∧c∧d)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, truthtable

There is proberly a simple answer to this and a more elegant than i have. I have a login form in html. You can login with your *ID* or your *Firstname, Lastname* and *email*. In JS i want to validate the form, i want to see if the *ID* field is filled or **all** 3 of the other fields.

Here is a turth table of this: 
[Truth table: a∨(b∧c∧d)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TIFO.png)

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return FormValidation()" name="login" method="POST">
     ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
     <p> or </p>
     Firstname: <input type="text" name="first"><br>
     Lastname: <input type="text" name="last"><br>
     Birthdate: <input type="date" name="birthdate"><br>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function FormValidation(){
    var id = document.forms["login"]["id"].value;
    var firstname = document.forms["login"]["firstname"].value;
    var lastname = document.forms["login"]["lastname"].value;
    var birthdate = document.forms["login"]["birthdate"].value;

    if (id == "" && (firstname == "" && lastname == "" && birthdate =="")) {
       alert("Something is missing");
       return false;
    } else if (id != "" && (firstname == "" && lastname == "" && birthdate =="")) {
       alert("Ok");
       return true;
    } else if (id == "" && (firstname != "" && lastname != "" && birthdate !="")) {
       alert("Ok");
       return true;
    } else if (id != "" && (firstname != "" && lastname != "" && birthdate !="")) {
       alert("Ok");
       return true;
    } else if .....
       .....
    }
```

There are for every error a if statement.

Please show me a more elegant way than this..

Comment: `return id !== "" || firstname !== "" && lastname !== "" && birthdate !== ""` or simply `return Boolean(id || firstname && lastName && birthdate);`

Comment: It looks like he's just expanding the truth table in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be overcomplicating this with if statements. Using logical notation maps to JavaScript quite nicely - no need to build out the truth table.

```
var hasId = id != "";
var hasFirstLastAndBirthday = firstname != "" && lastname != "" && birthday != "";

return hasId || hasFirstLastAndBirthday;
```

Comment: Didn't knew this was possible. Now in know for the next times! Many thanks!